Angular new control flow @for with async pipe and aliasing variable with as
I migrated from the structural directives *ngIf and *ngFor to the new control flow with @if and @for in Angular.
But there is one case that I used previously but I cannot seem to get it to work with the new control flow. Tried to find some more information also online but didn't find anything specific on this particular case so I decided to post here.
I used to do:
*ngFor="let option of options$ | async as options"

But neither of these seem to work:
@for(option of options$ | async; as options, track option)
@for(option of options$ | async; as options; track option)
@for(option of (options$ | async; as options); track option)

So I ended up splitting it into an @if and @for combination like so:
@if (options$ | async; as options) {
  @for(option of options) {
    ...
  }
}

But it would be nice to make it work in one line. Is there some valid syntax to make this combination of async pipe and aliasing a variable work?

aliasing for @for is currently not supported:https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/53233

@Chellappanவ If you post that as an answer I will accept it and close the question.

As of Angular 18, you can create aliases for @if block , but aliasing @for is not currently supported.
@if (options$ | async; as options) {
  @for(option of options) {
    ...
  }
}

For More Information

Yes, this works well. As I also wrote in my question this is exactly what I ended up using as a workaround.

You can just directly use like this, there is no need to define a local variable (options).
@for(option of (options$ | async); track option) {
    <div>{{option.name}}</div>
}

If you require the full options, then I recommend a wrapped if condition, here you can use options variable inside the for loop.
@if (options$ | async; as options) {
    @for(option of options; track option) {
        <div>{{option.name}}</div>
    }
}


Thanks for your answer. I understand there is no need for the alias, but in some cases it is just nice to have the alias (maybe not obvious in this simplified example).

@Wilt Let only allows Unknown "let" parameter variable "(options$ | async)". The allowed variables are: $index, $first, $last, $even, $odd, $count I get this error!

@Wilt Future version of angular will allow you to leverage @let so you can do `
@let greeting = 'Hello, ' + name + '!';
{{ greeting }}
` [@let introduction link](https://dev.to/oler/introduction-to-let-in-angular-18-cm6)